# Timeout::Error using selenium-webdriver in ruby

Tags: ruby, automation, cucumber, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have been getting a Timeout error ever since I started developing my tests. At first I thought it was related to the efficiency of my xpaths but after seeing the test pass quickly numerous times I don't think it is related to the selectors. The error randomly occurs and often when it does it occurs multiple times within a feature. I need to fix or at least understand what this problem is.

An example of a step definition:

```
When /^I navigate to "(.*)"$/ do |webpage|
navigate_to(webpage)
end
```

This is the error I get:

```
 Timeout::Error (Timeout::Error)
      /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:146:in `rescue in rbuf_fill'
      /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:140:in `rbuf_fill'
      /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readuntil'
      /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:132:in `readline'
      /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2562:in `read_status_line'
      /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2551:in `read_new'
      /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1319:in `block in transport_request'
      /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `catch'
      /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `transport_request'
      /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1293:in `request'
      /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1286:in `block in request'
      /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
      /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1284:in `request'
      ./features/support/env.rb:88:in `block in get_page_url'
```

The env.rb :

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'rspec'
require 'rspec/expectations'
require 'httpclient'
require 'fileutils.rb'
require 'pathname'

$driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :ie
#accept_next_alert = true
$driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 300
$driver.manage.timeouts.script_timeout = 300
$driver.manage.timeouts.page_load = 300
#verification_errors = []

AfterStep do
 sleep 5
end

at_exit do
    $driver.close
end
```

I have gone through numerous questions about this very same topic and none seem to have an answer that works, if an answer at all.

Similar issue. I have tried the solutions provided here but my error still persist
https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4414675

I have tried adding explicit waits as such:
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

I need to get this issue sorted out so please ask questions if I wasn't clear on anything.

Here is a list of installed gems:

```
archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
builder (3.2.0)
bundler (1.3.5)
childprocess (0.3.9)
columnize (0.3.6)
commonwatir (4.0.0)
cucumber (1.2.3)
debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
debugger-ruby_core_source (1.2.2)
diff-lcs (1.2.1)
ffi (1.5.0, 1.0.9)
gherkin (2.11.6)
hoe (3.6.2)
httpclient (2.3.2)
io-console (0.3)
json (1.7.7)
linecache19 (0.5.12)
mime-types (1.23)
mini_magick (3.6.0)
mini_portile (0.5.0)
minitest (2.12.1, 2.5.1)
multi_json (1.7.1)
nokogiri (1.5.9)
rack (1.5.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rake (10.0.3, 0.9.6)
rautomation (0.9.2)
rb-readline (0.5.0)
rdoc (3.12.1)
rspec (2.13.0)
rspec-core (2.13.1)
rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
rspec-mocks (2.13.0)
ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25)
ruby-debug19 (0.11.6)
ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
rubygems-update (2.0.3)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
s4t-utils (1.0.4)
selenium-webdriver (2.33.0, 2.31.0)
subexec (0.2.3)
user-choices (1.1.6.1)
watir (4.0.2)
watir-classic (3.7.0)
watir-webdriver (0.6.2)
websocket (1.0.7)
win32-api (1.4.8)
win32-process (0.7.2)
win32screenshot (1.0.8)
windows-api (0.4.2)
windows-pr (1.2.2)
xml-simple (1.1.2)
xpath (2.0.0)
```

Comment: Do you recycle the apppool or reset IIS before you hit that page? If yes, this may slow down the site when you first visit that page. You might see into the build scripts or ask one of your dev.

Comment: Have a look at https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1439 - there might be some ideas there. (we are having similar issues)

Comment: Thank you! I am having the same output as mgeh when I run cucumber with --backtrace. I will try a few of these solutions. I am not using webmock .

Comment: I'm not doing anything to explicitly recycle the apppool or reset IIS. I will look into this. Thanks!

Comment: @megaxelize could you show the value of 'webpage' variable that you are trying to navigate to?

Comment: Apologies I did not notice your comment. I will find out if I can share this information.

Answer (score 2):

I have edited the env.rb since posting this and have updated that part of the question. This may not be the absolute fix but it is something I have noticed that to me- has fixed part of the problem.

I changed the timeouts in the env.rb from 300 to 20.

```
$driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 20
$driver.manage.timeouts.script_timeout = 20
$driver.manage.timeouts.page_load = 20
```

Upon doing that my test suite now executes much faster and instead of lengthy timeout errors I am getting real errors pertaining to my code (poor selector, wrong method etc).

Timeouts I used to get for simply navigating to a page have become:

```
 Timed out waiting for page to load. (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::TimeOutError)
```

Which is appearing in less than 20 seconds but it may be due to the connection I have with the web page. I will be researching this error more in the near future.

If anyone tries this please let me know how it worked out for you (even if it didn't). I will keep updating this as I learn more.

Comment: I've been fighting this comment to recently.  I don't like it but what's working best right now is:
$driver.manage.timeouts.script_timeout = -1
$driver.manage.timeouts.page_load = -1
The script on this page is slow; but I only have this problem with one test (out of thousands).

Comment: Interesting, I will try it

Comment: I tried this and the lengthy timeout error re-appeared. That was the only difference I noticed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [discussion](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4414675) of this problem on `Ruby` forum.

There seemed to be not fix for it as for 19 July 2013, but there is a proposal to 
extend the amount of time before a failure with:

```
 driver.manage.timeouts.page_load = 300 # 5 minutes
```

Comment: Thank you! I have already done this and the timeout occurs well before 300 seconds.

Comment: I believe that is the the same link I provide in my question. I have also posted my issue on there as well.

Comment: @megaxelize - dont scary to upvote if the answer was helpful ))

Comment: Thank you but the answer did not provide any new information and repeated information provided in the question. Your input it appreciated though.

Comment: @megaxelize - isnt it the answer - iformation that bug not fixed?

Comment: The fix suggested on that site does not work in my situation. I posted it because I wanted others to clearly see I have tried extending the timeout.

Comment: @megaxelize - and if you try to extend all posible timeouts? To localize it

Comment: Still occurs! I may possibly have the solution but I do not have time to test thoroughly until Sunday. I will report back!

Comment: Nope wasn't the solution. I thought it had something to do with the type of variable driver was declared as (global, instance, class etc) but changing the driver to a global ($driver) did not stop the error.

Comment: @megaxelize - for me there can be 2 situation - timer is solution - or as the link in my post shows its a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer has issues with xpaths more than the other browsers. I used to run into this problem using webdriver and java.  Have you tried instantiating a Selector using a css selector and seeing if that helps the browser locate the element?

Comment: The error also occurs with firefox. I am converting more of my commands to css selectors to see if that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not the selectors as the problem happens despite. Thank you though! I am converting to just using css selectors anyway. When I first saw the error I thought it was due to selectors not being specific enough and decided to use xpaths. That is definitely not the case either.

Answer (score 0):

try delete\ing cache folder located in tmp/cache in your rails application and also run 'rake assets:clean:all' at the root of your application

Comment: I am not using rails. I am not sure if this would help but nor do I know a way to perform this task in my project. I will research your suggestions though and report back. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error with watir-webdriver, in my case I was attempting to visit:

```
@browser.goto "localhost:3000/#/login"
```

When I should have been visiting:

```
@browser.goto "http://localhost:3000/#/login"
```

Strangely enough my first scenario calling this method worked but when attempting to navigate that same URL on my second scenario I received a stack similar trace to yours

Answer (score 0):

I'm using selenium for scraping and not for test right now and I'm dealing with that something like this:

```
browser_name = :chrome
http_client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new(open_timeout: 5.minutes, read_timeout: 5.minutes)
@browser = Watir::Browser.new browser_name, http_client: http_client
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabling `--headless` option was what worked in my case.